# Normal Line vs Dash Line

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paint

You'll see in the picture that, on the left is a normal line and on right is a dashed line. After I selected the dashed line, the normal line was transformed into a dashed line. If I try to paint with a normal line, it will transform the dashed line in normal line.

[image: The two lines]

**Here is the `View` I used to create each line**:

```
public void setDashLine(){

    dashedLine = true;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
}

public void setNormalLine(){
    //paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    dashedLine = false;

    paint.setPathEffect(null);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(null);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
}


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if(dashedLine){
        paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
    }
    else {
        paint.setPathEffect(null);
    }


final OnTouchListener drawLineListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              myLine = new MyLine();
              myLine.xStart = event.getX();
              myLine.yStart = event.getY();

            return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            myLine.xEnd = event.getX();
            myLine.yEnd = event.getY();
            invalidate();
            lineList.add(myLine); 
            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
};

final OnTouchListener drawDashedLineListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
};
```

Comment: You should trim down that class to only the most relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Should you call:
paint = new Paint(); 
in 
public void setNormalLine()?